# Only one process prints in unix, multiprocessing python

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have a script where I'm loading a file which takes a while because there is quite much data to read and to prevent the user from terminating the process I want to show some kind of loading indication. I thought this was a good opportunity to learn how to use the multiprocessing module so I wrote this example to test the module:

```
import time, multiprocessing

def progress():
    delay = 0.5
    while True:
        print "Loading.",
        time.sleep(delay)
        print "\b.",
        time.sleep(delay)
        print "\b.",
        time.sleep(delay)
        print "\r                        \r",

    return

def loader(filename, con):
    # Dummy loader
    time.sleep(5)
    con.send(filename)
    con.close()
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parrent_con, child_con = multiprocessing.Pipe()
    filename = "main.key"

    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=progress)
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=loader, args=(filename, child_con))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    data = parrent_con.recv()
    p1.terminate()
    print "\n", data
```

It works as I expect when I run it in windows cmd, it prints "Loading" and sequentially adds dots until the loader is complete. 
But in unix where I need it to work I don't get any output from progress function, process p1.

Comment: I don't know the pythonic method, but the problem is buffering. By default, Linux buffers each line, and since you are not sending `\n`, nothing gets updated. Try running the program with `\n` instead of `\r`. If that works, you need to figure out how to disable line buffering in python. In C, the command is `setvbuf`

Comment: I was thinking of buffering as well. Does it work if you put some `sys.stdout.flush()` around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as Mark and Dacav suggested, buffering is the problem. Here are some possible solutions:

- Using `python -u` to run the script

  `python -u` will unbuffer stdout and stderr. This is the easiest solution if it's acceptable to you.
- Using `sys.stdout.flush`

  `sys.stdout.flush` will flush the stdout from buffer.

  ```
  delay = 0.5
  while True:
      print("Loading."),
      sys.stdout.flush()
      time.sleep(delay)
      print("\b."),
      sys.stdout.flush()
      time.sleep(delay)
      print("\b."),
      sys.stdout.flush()
      time.sleep(delay)
      print("\r                        \r"),
      sys.stdout.flush()
  return
  ```